# Google maps - InfoWindows for multiple polygons

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to get google maps infowindow for multiple polygons?
I manage to get multiple polygons, but I have problem to show info window for every polygon and center info window on polygon.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ow8kb0vn/

```js
var editedPolygons = [
   [
      [
         {
            "lat":14.56754606924714,
            "lng":120.99225461483002
         },
         {
            "lat":14.567213783453319,
            "lng":120.9916752576828
         },
         {
            "lat":14.566736121747363,
            "lng":120.99207758903503
         }
      ],
      {
         "color":"green",
         "title":"---------------------------------------info content green"
      }
   ],
   [
      [
         {
            "lat":14.566383066777853,
            "lng":120.99221169948578
         },
         {
            "lat":14.566325954891425,
            "lng":120.99138557910919
         },
         {
            "lat":14.565635419093956,
            "lng":120.9915840625763
         },
         {
            "lat":14.565635419093956,
            "lng":120.9925840625763
         }
      ],
      {
         "color":"red",
         "title":"----------------------------------------------info content red"
      }
   ]
];

var map;

function initialize() {
    var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.5667, 120.9927),
        zoom: 17,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    for (var i = 0; i < editedPolygons.length; i++) {
        var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
         fillColor: editedPolygons[i][1].color,
         strokeWeight: 2,
          path: editedPolygons[i][0],
          map: map
        });
        
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
       content: editedPolygons[i][1].title
     });
        
      poly.addListener('click', function() {
       infowindow.open(map, poly);
     });
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #googleMap {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry,drawing&ext=.js"></script>
<div id="googleMap"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The InfoWindow needs a position.  You can either use a `google.maps.Marker` as the second argument to the `open` method (or pass in an `MVCObject` with a `position` property) or set its position when you create it.

from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow)

> an anchor can be any MVCObject that exposes a LatLng position property

simplest way to set it to be the center of the polygon is to compute the center of the polygon's bounds and use that.

```
// use function closure to associate the infowindow with the polygon
poly.addListener('click', (function(content) {
  return function() {
    // set the content
    infowindow.setContent(content);
    // set the position
    infowindow.setPosition(this.center);
    // open it
    infowindow.open(map);
  }
})(editedPolygons[i][1].title));
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k1wg6jb0/)

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.5667, 120.9927),
    zoom: 17,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
  for (var i = 0; i < editedPolygons.length; i++) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
      fillColor: editedPolygons[i][1].color,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      path: editedPolygons[i][0],
      map: map
    });

    for (var pathidx = 0; pathidx < poly.getPath().getLength(); pathidx++) {
      bounds.extend(poly.getPath().getAt(pathidx));
    }
    // store the computed center as a property of the polygon for easy access
    poly.center = bounds.getCenter();
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var title = editedPolygons[i][1].title;
    // use function closure to associate the infowindow with the polygon
    poly.addListener('click', (function(content) {
      return function() {
        // set the content
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        // set the position
        infowindow.setPosition(this.center);
        // open it
        infowindow.open(map);
      }
    })(editedPolygons[i][1].title));
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
var editedPolygons = [
  [
    [{
      "lat": 14.56754606924714,
      "lng": 120.99225461483002
    }, {
      "lat": 14.567213783453319,
      "lng": 120.9916752576828
    }, {
      "lat": 14.566736121747363,
      "lng": 120.99207758903503
    }], {
      "color": "green",
      "title": "---------------------------------------info content green"
    }
  ],
  [
    [{
      "lat": 14.566383066777853,
      "lng": 120.99221169948578
    }, {
      "lat": 14.566325954891425,
      "lng": 120.99138557910919
    }, {
      "lat": 14.565635419093956,
      "lng": 120.9915840625763
    }, {
      "lat": 14.565635419093956,
      "lng": 120.9925840625763
    }], {
      "color": "red",
      "title": "----------------------------------------------info content red"
    }
  ]
];
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,drawing&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="googleMap"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact the `infowindow` variable changes over time (it points to a different object every time `i` changes within the loop).

If you replace

```
poly.addListener('click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map, poly);
            });
```

with

```
(function(infowindow) {
          poly.addListener('click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, poly);
          });
        })(infowindow);
```

it will work, because the anonymous function will force the code to keep track of the good object.

To display the infowindow at the center of the polygon, you'll have to compute where is this center. And then pass it to the infowindow object (it has a `position` property).